# How to create a map marker like airbnb, nestaway

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-markers

I have tried following code

```
var contentString = '<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;"> ' +
              '<p class="text-center" style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">' +
                '<span style="margin:0px;padding:0px;font-size:15px;"> ' +
                  '<strong> ₹ '+
                    // '<img class="pull-left" src="assets/img/site-logo/new_site_logo_favicon.png" alt="Brand Logo" height="20px">' +
                    obj1[i].price +
                  '</strong>' +
                '</span>' +
              '</p>' +
            '</div>';
            var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString,
                map: map,
                position: latLng
            });
```

Which gives the following result?

When on page loads first time:

[image]

When I load it dynamically using $.ajax + jQuery:

[image]

My first problem is, The close icon is not hiding for first time with the help of this code:

```
$('.gm-style-iw').next("div").remove();
```

But second time it does disappear. How do I do it first time correctly?

Second problem is, I want to have a marker like airbnb and nestaway like given in the image.

AirBNB Map Marker:

[image]

Nestaway Marker:

[image]

It changes color and few animation stuff. How do i do it onhovering the linked card.